# Using css in Razor Grid output

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using the grid output of razor, and i want to give the output of one column a different colour, if it satisfies the condition.

When the column Snapshot Size is greater than 10000 and less than 20000 the css class "Warning" should be used, when the return value is greater than 20000 the class "critical" should be used, otherwise the "normal" class should be used. if anyone can help me, I am very grateful for. hopefully I can do this myself next month when I followed the training

the css code

```
.normal {
    font-size:13px;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #729ea5;
    background:#edfafa;
}

    .warning {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #729ea5;
    color: #E08B1B;
    background:#edfafa;

    }
    .critical {
    font-weight: bold;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #729ea5;
    color:red;
    background:#edfafa;
    }
```

Razor code

```
 @grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "grid",
headerStyle: "head",
alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    columns: grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("SystemName"),
    grid.Column("ServerDescription"),        
    grid.Column("SnapShotName"),
    grid.Column("SnapshotDescription"),       
    grid.Column(header: "SnapshotSize: MB", format: 
    @<text>
    @if(SnapshotSize > 10000  && SnapshotSize < 20000 )
    {
       <label class="warning">@item.SnapshotSize </label>
    }
   else if(SnapshotSize > 20000 )
    {
       <label class="Critical">@item.SnapshotSize </label>
    }
   else 
    {
       <label class="normal ">@item.SnapshotSize </label>
    }
    </text>, style: "casestatus"),                 
    grid.Column("DatastoreFreeSpace","LUN free: GB"),
    grid.Column("Creator"),
    grid.Column("Vcenter")
)        

)
```

If i run the the above code, i get the following error on line 82.

Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:

```
Line 80:         grid.Column("SnapShotName"),
Line 81:         grid.Column("SnapshotDescription"),       
Line 82:         grid.Column(header: "SnapshotSize: MB", format: 
Line 83:         @<text>
Line 84:         @if(SnapshotSize > 10000  && SnapshotSize < 20000 )
```

Comment: What is actually the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("SystemName"),
        ...
        grid.Column(header: "SnapshotSize: MB", format: 
        @<text>
        @if(item.SnapshotSize > 10000  && item.SnapshotSize < 20000 )
        {
           <label style="Warning">@item.SnapshotSize </label>
        }
       else if(SnapshotSize > 20000 )
        {
           <label style="Critical">@item.SnapshotSize </label>
        }
       else 
        {
           <label style="normal ">@item.SnapshotSize </label>
        }
        </text>, style: "casestatus"),
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I get the next error on line 78              Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments

Source Error:


Line 76:         columns: grid.Columns(
Line 77:         grid.Column("SystemName"),
Line 78:         grid.Column(header: "SnapshotSize MB", format: 
Line 79:         @<text>
Line 80:         @if(SnapshotSize > 10000  && SnapshotSize < 20000 )

Comment: check edited answer..i have tested it and works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
        @grid.Column(format: (item) =>
    {
        string classAttr = string.Empty;

        if (100 > item.value > 1000)
            classAttr = "warning";
        else if (1000 > item.value > 10000)
            classAttr = "critical";
        else
            classAttr = "none";

        return Html.Raw(string.Format("<label class='{0} />'", classAttr));
    }, style: "casestatus");
```